# In tensorflow, is there any c++ function or methods for resizing memory in GPU?

Tags: c++, tensorflow, memory

I'm working on making some operation in tensorflow.

In C++, I have the issue that I couldn't set the shape of the output size of tensor(set_output function) until I make some calculation with inputs.

Is there any way for setting output tensor without shape? I want to set the output shape after some process in operation function.

Or is there any way for modifying the size of output tensor in the operation?

Thanks.

Comment: Please be more specific and show some research and or coding attempt.

Comment: I actually have Op which has input and output. However I want to set the output shape after I calculate the row of the output in the operation with input. How can I do that?